# How to make in Intellij IDEA the generated method to be at the end of the class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

In Intellij IDEA, inside a method, you can write something as:

```
myNewMethod(someParam);
```

Then if you go with the cursor on `myNewMethod` and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac) you can choose `Create method 'myNewMethod'` which will create the new method with the expected parameters and return type.

The problem is that this new method is created immediately after the method which is in, and not at the end. I would like to generate it at the end of the class.

For example I have a public method and I generate the 3 methods in order:

```
public methodPublic() {
    myGenerated1();
    myGenerated2();
    myGenerated3();
}
```

it will end up generating them:

```
public methodPublic() {
    myGenerated1();
    myGenerated2();
    myGenerated3();
} 

private void myGenerated3() { ... }

private void myGenerated2() { ... }

private void myGenerated1() { ... }
```

Comment: This is by design, but you are welcome to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: You can place the cursor where you want to put the methods, but to make it generally, I don't know any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know still there is no option in Intellij Idea  to insert generated method to end of the file except getters and setters. But you can sort them in alphabetic order.

Go to `File > Setting > Editor > Code Style > Java > Arrangement Tab`. Click on the small pencil icon which is placed next to item called `method` under `Matching Rules` section.
In there select `order by name` option from `Order` dropdown.

[image]

You can create feature request in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA